# How to fix Mail stuck importing messages from a Time Machine backup?

Tags: mail.app, backup, email, time-machine

I'm setting up a new Mac from an old one, and everything's working perfect, except for getting Mail set up.

This is what I'm seeing with Mail:

[image]

The "Time remaining" figure just keeps increasing, while the "Imported X of Y messages" number gets stuck on 14.

I've tried searching Apple's support community, but none of the suggestions there have helped. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is IMAP or Exchange you can skip this process and just add your account afterwards.

I would not advise to skip it if it was a POP3 account because usually it means you only have a local copy of those mailboxes and won't get synced when adding the account again.